# Jquery checkbox check fail after browsers back button is pressed in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have asp.net page has check boxes.

If I check the check box and go to different page and go back the first page using browser's **back button**, following jquery code fails in Chrome and IE although **checkbox is checked**.

```
 $('#keywordsdiv input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
     attarr += this.checked ? "," + $(this).val() : "";
 });
```

This works in FF perfectly.

Also this script works in Chrome and IE if I call the function from the page.

I've confirmed that Chrome and IE run the code block, but they think checkbox is not checked although it is checked.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Maybe try $(this).is(':checked') instead of this.checked?

Comment: what is `attarr`, is defined anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a longshot without seeing the rest of the code, but can you enclose this inside a document.ready() statement? That would make sure the rest of the page is loaded before you attempt to access the checkboxes in it.

i.e:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    .... your code ...        

    $('#keywordsdiv input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        attarr += this.checked ? "," + $(this).val() : "";
    });

    ... your code ...
});
```